# What's up with the [tag:structure]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just saw [structure] was used the other day and had 5 entries, anyone have objections if I remove this tag and add more specific ones to the entries in question? Mainly:

[Why aren't rockets built with truss structures inside their fuel & oxidizer tanks to increase structural strength?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38103/why-arent-rockets-built-with-truss-structures-inside-their-fuel-oxidizer-tank)

[Are there liquid fueled rocket boosters having coaxial fuel/oxidizer tanks?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38147/are-there-liquid-fueled-rocket-boosters-having-coaxial-fuel-oxidizer-tanks)

[How does Orbex save structural weight by using coaxial tanks?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38219/how-does-orbex-save-structural-weight-by-using-coaxial-tanks)

[What is "additional line load" [N/mm] for the Ariane 5 launch vehicle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38331/what-is-additional-line-load-n-mm-for-the-ariane-5-launch-vehicle)

[How did NASA decide on its missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38804/how-did-nasa-decide-on-its-missions)

Let me know what you think a less generic term for "structure" is on a per-question basis, or if no edits are needed.

Answer (score 6):

The first four use structure in a different way than the last. For the first four, I think the [design](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag would work well, or the more specific [engine-design](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-design).

For the last one, it is talking about structuring plans for an agency. I think the [planning](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) tag would be better there.

Comment: I'll wait 24hrs for votes then make the edits, don't bother yourself with it, thanks again for all you do; I don't visit meta or thank you enough. If you have a moderation donation fund I'd love to support it if it's not against SE rules, Paetron may be a great idea.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I appreciate the thought, but I mod for free. I think it works best pro bono. I'm happy to continue helping out as long as life doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Wait, where's my bribe?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I went ahead and changed the tags as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "structure" is really bad but if a change is needed how about "structural design"?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad tag *per se*, but it does seem to have been created haphazardly, used only on a few questions, and not clearly defined. If you want to create a structural design tag and add it to relevant questions, you're welcome to!

Comment: Since you went ahead and created [tag:structural-design], I made [tag:structure] a synonym of it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and add some info.  I have not dealt with tags much.